# Unable to get typescript formArray to HTML

Tags: angular, typescript

This is the link I referred as an example.and this is my code. can you please anyone give me suggestions?
      https://plnkr.co/edit/8OKiQMK788R2uCt2OWzm?p=preview

```
public pcform: FormGroup;
public hobbiesArray = [];
public pcmisc: Array<any>;

constructor(public serviceprovider:ServiceProvider,public navCtrl:NavController,public navParams: NavParams,public formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.pcform = formBuilder.group({
        SelectDivision: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
    })

}

ngOnInit() {
    this.serviceprovider.PC_MISC().subscribe( res => {
        this.pcmisc=res.json();
        var pcmiskk= this.pcmisc
    }, error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
    console.log(pcmiskk);  
}

get hobbiesList(): FormArray {
    for (let hobby of this.pcmisc) {
        console.log(hobby.detailDescription);
        this.hobbiesArray.push(this.formBuilder.group({
            isChosen: false,
            detailDescription: hobby.detailDescription,
            lookup:hobby,
        }));

        this.pcform = this.formBuilder.group({
            hobbiesList: this.formBuilder.array(this.hobbiesArray)
        });
    }
    return this.pcform.get('hobbiesList') as FormArray;
}
```

In HTML this is what I have done

```
<div formArrayName="hobbiesList">  
    <div *ngFor="let hobby of hobbiesList.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i" >
        <input type="checkbox" formControlName="isChosen"  /> {{hobby.controls.detailDescription.value}}
    </div>
</div>
```

but its keep on showing error like

1. ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'hobbiesList -> 0'
2. ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
3. ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find control with name: 'hobbiesList'
4. Error: Cannot find control with name: 'hobbiesList'

Comment: call hobbiesList() function from sucess subscribe

Comment: How can i call HobbiesList() function inside success.its showing cannot find name "HobbiesList"

Comment: declare hobbiesArray= []

Comment: res => {  this.pcmisc=res.json();
for (let hobby of this.pcmisc) {....
     get this.hobbiesList: FormArray {
    return this.pcform.get('hobbiesList') as FormArray;
  }; } }, }this is how you are saying right by declaring hobbiesArray=[]?